# How to get email content from documents app in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get content from google docs for email body in Html format in app script as earlier I was using classic google sites for getting body content of the email and now the classic sites are shutting down. Or do you know any alternative for this . Earlier I was using code for getting content.

`SitesApp.getPageByUrl(spSignURL).getHtmlContent()`

Answer (score 0):

You may export the document as HTML. To do so you may use the following function:

```js
function exportAsHtml(documentId) {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder()  // Makes Apps Script get the right permissions
  
  const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${documentId}/export?mimeType=text%2Fhtml`, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    },
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  })

  const content = result.getContentText()

  if (result.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
    console.error(JSON.parse(content))
    throw new Error("Exception when exporting as HTML")
  }

  return content
}
```

The first line of the function makes it so Apps Script grants you the necessary permissions. Alternatively you can manually set all the permissions you are using at the manifest.

It's worth noting that email HTML is not 100% the same as web HTML, so you may need to clean the result a bit depending on your use case.

### References

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Files: export (Google Drive API reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: The script is for premade templates and it gets decided by certain parameters on selecting which template should be used. This script cant be added to the current script I need to add script that takes in variable and when the script is working it takes the value of variable and send the mail

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like Apps Script HTML templates ([read the guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)). You just need to use `getContent()` ([read reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getContent())) to get it as a string.

Comment: Yes need something like `.getContent()` like I have been using this function to get content from html file `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(spSignURL).getContent();` But it is not working with document app it showing error please suggest any alternative or any other way if I am doing this wrong this is my current code for Docs `DocumentApp.openByUrl(msgURL).getBody().getContent();` but it is not working and showing error -  Cannot find function getContent in object DocumentBodySection.

Comment: Are you using HTML? Do you want to use Docs as an email editor? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We had made this script for our employees we have standard templates of mails for the particular event, for example, We have standard mail for the introduction of the company it was made on google site and published whenever an employee needs to send a mail he or she just fills a google form and select the template they wish to send after submitting the entry is recorded in sheets and the script ran it checked the template No took the link and send the mail to the customer. But now as the classic site is going away we need alternative and we think it can be replaced by Docs.

Comment: There is a dropdown in the forms of templates name. The person selects the name of the template they wish to send after that the script checks the template selected goes to the template sheet takes the URL from there and after taking content from there it sends the mail.

Comment: So you want to be able to modify the templates without knowing HTML and would like to be able to add values dynamically. This is quite a project and not a simple question anymore. I would leave some sort of text marker on the template (something that marks what to add where), then I'd use my solution to generate the HTML, and I'd use javascript `string.replaceAll` to add the values where they need to be.